# Prawn: specify page for content to be placed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I'm currently using Prawn to generate a billing PDF, the problem is that the total amount of the bill is known at the end of the rendering. I'd like to place this variable's content on the first page of PDF but I don't how to add content to a page once I used the `start_new_page` function.

Is that possible to go back on the fist page and add content once I used `start_new_page`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out the [go_to_page](http://prawnpdf.org/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html#method-i-go_to_page) method.